# Script to rename files in subfolders to different name

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I have a directory with several folders inside. Inside the folders I have a worksheet with the same name in all folders. I need to run a script that randomly changes the name of the worksheets so that I can throw them all in the same folder. For example: worksheet1
worksheet2
worksheet3.
today they are all called spreadsheet.csv
I have a sketch in linux.

need help please.

```
NN=0; 
for arq in $(ls -1 *.csv);do
let NN++; 
rename -n 's/'${arq}'/spreadsheet'${NN}'.csv/' ${arq};
done
```

(this search all files csv, but dont is recursive. Work only in one directory)

Comment: I have removed all references to Windows and batch files. Not only was your code not valid for a batch file, this site does not offer answers for multiple languages or scripts. You already have an answer for Linux, so I have removed references other than for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `globstar`:

```
n=0
shopt -s globstar nullglob || exit

for f in **/*.csv; do
    until dst=spreadsheet$(( ++n )).csv; [[ ! -e ${dst} ]]; do
        continue
    done

    mv -i -- "${f}" "${dst}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample files:

```
$ find . -name "*.csv"
./spreadsheet.csv
./sub1/spreadsheet.csv
./sub1/sub2/spreadsheet.csv
```

One idea:

```
n=0

while read -r oldname
do
    ((++n))
    newname="${oldname##*/}"
    newname="${newname//.csv/-$n.csv}"
    echo mv "$oldname" "$newname"
done < <(find . -name spreadsheet.csv)
```

This generates:

```
mv ./spreadsheet.csv spreadsheet-1.csv
mv ./sub1/spreadsheet.csv spreadsheet-2.csv
mv ./sub1/sub2/spreadsheet.csv spreadsheet-3.csv
```

Once OP is satisifed with the output, remove the `echo` and run the script again.

After removing the `echo` and running again:

```
$ find . -name "*.csv"
./spreadsheet-1.csv
./spreadsheet-2.csv
./spreadsheet-3.csv
```